# dropbox service fails or succedes depending on time spent at the login screen

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, i3, lightdm, dropbox

I think I've been doing more than a dozen system reboots in the last few minutes to check this strange behavior.
It seems that the service of dropbox succedes or fails in running at startup depending on how much time I spend at the login screen where I enter the password. I've not done any timing, so I don't know what *much time* exactly is, but it's not more than a half a dozen seconds.

When I enter the password quickly, Dropbox starts up, indeed I verify the following,

```
$ systemctl status dropbox@enrico.service
● dropbox@enrico.service - Dropbox
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dropbox@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dropbox@enrico.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-06-13 17:07:04 CEST; 6min ago
 Main PID: 1006 (dropbox)
    Tasks: 84 (limit: 19660)
   Memory: 148.0M
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-dropbox.slice/dropbox@enrico.service
           ├─1006 /usr/bin/dropbox
           ├─1052 dbus-launch --autolaunch 9f3c6fabb4aa40d1b7d5b3a3881af003 --binary-syntax --close-stderr
           ├─1053 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-only --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
           └─1057 /usr/bin/dunst

Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dropbox[1006]: dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets.so'
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dropbox[1006]: dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/PyQt5.QtWidgets.so'
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dropbox[1006]: dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.so'
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dropbox[1006]: dropbox: load fq extension '/opt/dropbox/PyQt5.QtDBus.so'
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dbus-daemon[1053]: [session uid=1000 pid=1051] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.Notifications' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=1006 comm="/usr/bin/dropbox ")
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden org.freedesktop.Notifications[1053]: Warning: 'allow_markup' is deprecated, please use 'markup' instead.
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden org.freedesktop.Notifications[1053]: Warning: The frame section is deprecated, width has been renamed to frame_width and moved to the global section.
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden org.freedesktop.Notifications[1053]: Warning: The frame section is deprecated, color has been renamed to frame_color and moved to the global section.
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden org.freedesktop.Notifications[1053]: Warning: Unknown keyboard shortcut: mod4+grave
Jun 13 17:07:05 greywarden dbus-daemon[1053]: [session uid=1000 pid=1051] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Notifications'
```

On the other hand, when I'm too slow in entering the password (*e.g.* type, backspace, retype, ...) or I'm simply not looking at the screen while I'm reading a book, the output is

```
$ systemctl status dropbox@enrico.service
● dropbox@enrico.service - Dropbox
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dropbox@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dropbox@enrico.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-06-13 17:15:03 CEST; 39s ago
  Process: 1031 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dropbox (code=exited, status=250)
 Main PID: 1031 (code=exited, status=250)
```

and dropbox is indeed not running (no tray icon).

I'm running i3 on ArchLinux and LightDM login manager. I followed *Prevent automatic updates* and *Autostart* sections at [the wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox), but it's not unlikely that I made confusion between *Autostart on boot with systemd* and *Autostart on login with systemd* and that could be the root of the problem.

Comment: Run it as [a user service](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Autostart_on_login_with_systemd)

Comment: Have I to disable the non-user-run service? (`systemd` and services are something extremely obscure to me).

Comment: Yes, you only want one running.

Comment: It seems you've found the solution. Why don't you elaborate on it? Or, at least, could you provide some links to me that I can learn something from? (The wiki page is not useful to me, maybe not because of the page, but because of my total lack of notions and experience on the topic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the first comment to the question, [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dropbox#Autostart_on_login_with_systemd) wikipage solved the issue.